# How to extract all "put in cell" images from google spreadsheet in high resolution

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet with imported (Insert>Image>In cell) photos, which I would like to extract (save to disk) in their full resolution, i.e. how they show if I do right click>Image>Put image over cells.
Saving as web page etc only grabs images in their low-res form (how they show "in cell"). Can you please help me with a script, or something? Thanks!

Comment: I have a similar situation that I need help with. I have about 400 rows. Column 1 contains the TITLE, and column 2 has an IMAGE that was added using the "insert image in cell" option. I'd like to extract all images, and if it's not too difficult, name the file based on the TITLE in column 1.